# SOQL query to identify Account names with out any number

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql

I require to grab all account names which does not contain any number and display in the report.
I am trying to query it using LIKE, but it is not working.

My query - `[select name from account where NOT name like ('%1%','%2%')]`

Error -

> Unknown Error parsing Query

Here I am planning to add numbers from 0 to 9 so that it will return me only account names with characters, not number.

Plz help me out if one knows how to do it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This syntax is not supported in regular SOQL, but there's still way to do this in Apex code. We are allowed to bind like to a collection:

```
String[] filters = new String[0];
for(Integer i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
  filters.add('%'+i+'%');
}
Account[] records = [select name from account where not name like :filters];
```

This would find all accounts that meet your criteria, although it will fail if you have too many records, since this would be a non-selective query.

Answer (score 4):

Create a boolean formula field and perform all those checking about not having numbers and finally use that field in SOQL filter condition.